# Shortcut &= acting like & not &&

Tags: c#

```
public static void Main()
{
    var result = false;
    Xpto xpto = null;
    result &= xpto.Some;
}

public class Xpto
{
    public bool Some { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using C# 6.0 VS2015; the code above triggers a null exception.

The `&=` operator is behaving like the `&` operator. I would expect it to behave similar to `&&` and skip evaluation of the right side if value already false (see explanation of "short-circuit" behavior in [The conditional-AND operator (&&)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk.aspx) article).

Is this behavior intended or is it a bug?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/e669ax02.aspx

Comment: Anyone to translate it to english?

Comment: `&` performs a bitwise `AND` operation on integral types, and a logical `AND` on boolean types.

Comment: @Eser looks Endglish enough for me... If you need translation - "Why `&=` to does not behave like `&&` and instead behaves like `&` as described  in documentation/C# specification?".

Comment: Is it _that_ surprising that `&` behaves like `&`?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov even the translated sentence does not make sense. Ok. `&=` is bitwise but `&` is logical.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Sorry, I must be idiot. I still don't get what is asked in question. No one to edit the question?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, Eser made that comment way before it was edited. See the edit history and you will understand why such comment is made. Ruben did a awesome job editing it and making a possible valid question.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary what is bitwise? Both `&` and `&=` are *logical AND* for boolean type.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov oh. I did not know they are same. http://www.dotnetperls.com/and

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the documentation: [&= Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e669ax02.aspx):

> `x &= y`
>   is equivalent to `x = x & y`
>
> (...) The & operator performs a bitwise logical AND operation on integral operands and logical AND on bool operands.

I'm assuming you're trying to avoid the null check.

The code below will not throw an exception because you stated the `result` variable is `false`; in this case, the language optimization will *short-circuit* the expression and will not evaluate the second part:

```
result = result && xpto.Some;
```

If you're a on liner person, you can make it more same by writing:

```
result = result && (xpto == null ? true : xpto.Some);
```

or, in plain C#:

```
if (xpto != null)
   result = result && xpto.Some;
```

Comment: Note: Null ref exception will occur irrespective of using `&=` or `&&` per posted code since `xpto` is null.

Comment: @Rahul, the runtime optimization will kick in and skip the evaluation of the second term, as anything in an `AND` operation with a `false` argument will lead to a `false` result

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I made a radical edit in the original question, so please revert it if I took it wrong. I also aware the difference between bitwise and short-circuit, and I assumed the OP were trying to use the short circuit form, but he chose the wrong operator. I edited this answer to reflect your concern

Comment: @RubensFarias fair edit. I've sort-of reverted your change in question  - check it out (even with edits hard to justify as a good question)

Comment: Short-circuiting is not a “runtime optimization”—that terminology suggests that short-circuiting is something one compiler might do but another wouldn’t. It is a language guarantee to enable terseness and atomicity, just the same as `&` is guaranteed to always evaluate both operands. Unfortunately, `&=` exists but not `&&=`.